# Как создать подключение к postgres из докер контейнера?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, postgresql, docker

Всем привет!
У меня есть телеграм бот, которого я решил перенести в докер контейнер. Бот подключается к postgres бд. Контейнер и postgres запущены на одном сервере. При запуске контейнера получаю ошибку

> psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port
> 5432 failed: Connection refused
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

имя бд: happy_bot
имя пользователя (postgres): happy_bot

Вот pg_hba.conf :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
local   income_bot      income_bot                              password
local   happy_bot       happy_bot                               password
# IPv4 local connections:
# host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

сама строка подключения:

```
connection = pg.connect(database='happy_bot', user='happy_bot', password='happy_bot_password', host='127.0.0.1', port=5432)
```

Я пробовал писать в строке соединения host '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', ip сервера на котором запущена бд и контейнер

При запуске контейнера я пробовал добавлять --network='host', --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway

Я пробовал отключать фаервол ufw - не помогло

В голове уже каша, разные советы перепробовал, пока без результата. Помогите плиз

Answer (score 3):

Контейнер можно рассматривать как отдельный компьютер, работающий внутри вашей машины. У него своя локальная сеть, и он ничего не видит из того, что есть в вашем хосте.

Есть несколько способов достучаться до базы данных.

1. Запустить докер в с хостовой сетью: `docker run --network host ...`. В этом случае сетевые интерфейсы хоста, включая 127.0.0.1, будут видны внутри контейнера.
2. Создать для вашего контейнера выделенную подсеть.

```
$ docker network create bot
03d99fd377bafbbaccea1625edb3c78522528bf585f434bffaed453fe882e463
$ ifconfig 
br-03d99fd377ba: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        ether 02:42:11:3f:40:b3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

докер создасть сеть с именем `br-<hex-digits>` в котором шестнадцатиричные цифры равны первым 12 символам хэш-идентификатора сети.

В моём случае была создана сеть с префиксом `172.20.0.0/16`. В этой сети у хоста адрес `172.20.0.1`, а внутри контейнера адрес `172.20.0.2`. Контейнер запускать командой `docker run --network bot ...`.

Запустите постгрес, чтобы он слушал порт `5432` на адресе `172.20.0.1`, и используйте этот адрес внутри вашего контейнера для связи с постгресом.

3. Правильный вариант - воспользоваться `docker compose`.

Создайте `docker-compose.yaml` с двумя сервисами. Один сервис будет контейнер с вашим ботом, второй будет postgres.

Вариантов настройки docker-compose практически бесконечное множество. Вот пример:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    hostname: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes: 
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
  bot:
    # здесь параметры вашего контейнера
```

Здесь важны две штуки. Во-первых, в сервисе `db` указано имя узла (hostname) `postgres`. Именно по этому имени будет виден сервер базы данных в контейнере `bot`. Докер возьмёт на себя DNS-распознавание имени и подстановку нужного адреса.

Во-вторых, базы данных будут лежать в файловой системе хоста. Это делается в секции `volumes`: локальный путь `./db/data` мапится на путь `/var/lib/postgresql/data` внутри контейнера. При первом запуске контейнера база будет инциализирована скриптом `./db/init.sql`

Как-то так.